# windows command line pipe a string to groovy

Tags: windows, command-line, groovy, echo, pipe

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit and want to do something like below on the command line using Groovy:

echo "println('Hello, World...')" | groovy -e

But I can't seem to get the echo o/p to pass as i/p to the groovy command, and keep getting the below error:

error: illegal use of -e (requires a value)

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4):

Groovy doesn't have an option for reading the script from standard input.  The `-e` option is used to specify the script on the command line like this:

```
groovy -e "println('Hello World')"
```

If you really need to run a script piped into standard input, try this:

```
echo println('Hello World') | groovy -e 'new GroovyShell().evaluate(System.in)'
```

Comment: I tried the following code but nothing got printed on the console: `echo "println('Hello, World')" | groovy -e "new GroovyShell().evaluate(System.in)"`

Comment: Leave off the double quotes; they're passed through to groovy by the Windows command interpreter.